# Autohotkey, How to create drop-down list to select items

Tags: windows-10, script, macros, automation, autohotkey

I have few short hotstrings/hotkeys. If I type "one", there's a corresponding actions, if I typed two, there another corresponding actions.

My question is, how can I make a single hotkey for all, that when I press a key, a drop-down list/msgbox will appear, then I can choose an item, and upon clicking it, it will perform the corresponding macro based on the list below?

```
::one::

{

    do this

    do that

}

return

::two::

{

    do this

    do that

}

return

::three::

{

    do this

    do that

}

return

::four::

{

    do this

    do that

}

return

::five::

{

    do this

    do that

}

return
```

Also, is Autohotkey a good one for learning scripts? Or AutoIT? Or I should learn major scripting language (like the ones I usually heard - Perl, PhP, etc.)

We're those programming language able to do simple steps, like recording just keyboard pressing and mouse movements?

.
Thanks,

Faye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AHK-example:

```ahk
; create the gui:
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
; DropDownList:
; Gui, Add, DDL, gAction vChoice Choose1 w200, one|two|three|four
; ListBox:
Gui, Add, ListBox, gAction vChoice w200 h60, one|two|three|four
return

; Press F1 to show the gui:
F1::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, 40, 50, 0
Gui, Show, x0 y0, Actions
return


Action:
Gui, Submit ; or
; Gui, Submit, NoHide   ; if you don't want to hide the gui-window after an action
If (Choice = "one")
    MsgBox, 1st action 
If (Choice = "two")
    MsgBox, 2nd action
If (Choice = "three")
    MsgBox, 3rd action
If (Choice = "four")
    MsgBox, 4th action
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

**EDIT**

If you want to choose an action by using the Up/Down Arrows and Enter,
you need to add a **default Button** to the gui

or this:

```ahk
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Add, ListBox, gAction vChoice w200 h60, one|two|three|four
return

; Press F1 to show the gui:
F1:: Gui, Show, x0 y0, Actions

Action:
If ((A_GuiEvent = "DoubleClick") || (Trigger_Action))
{
    Gui, Submit
    If (Choice = "one")
        MsgBox, 1st action 
    If (Choice = "two")
        MsgBox, 2nd action
    If (Choice = "three")
        MsgBox, 3rd action
    If (Choice = "four")
        MsgBox, 4th action
}
return

#If WinActive("Actions ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI")

    Enter::
        Trigger_Action := true
        GoSub, Action
        Trigger_Action := false
    return
    
#If

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Comment: Hello @user3419297, thank you, this is very helpful for us. One more thing, can you please edit this a little bit 1.] Make the box bigger with all the options 1, 2, 3, 4 already showing (without the need to click the drop-down arrow to reveal the options), buttons maybe.. 2.] Make the autohotkey icon stay on the system tray.. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user3419297: Already using your 'answer' for our Invoice Recording Macro - DONE.. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user3419297: How can we make it to choose with using the Up/Down Arrows then pressing Enter (instead of the mouse)?

Comment: Thanks, working fine now. :) By the way, are these codes required or mandatory in every new script, because it's always there everytime I create ahk in notepad?: 
#NoEnv 
#Warn 
SendMode Input 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ?

Comment: They are NOT required in EVERY script. They are just [directives](http://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/Directives.html) or commands  recommended for better performance, compatibility, speed and reliability. You can remove or add more of them by editing the template file in the %WINDIR%\ShellNew folder. Check the individual description for each of them in the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/index.htm).

Comment: Why does nothing happen when I run this script? Im trying to work from examples, but this didn't do anything

Comment: @Kalamalka Kid, Did you press F1 to show the Gui?

Comment: oops THank you !